# Why doesn't Ruby find classes in a higher scope when module is specified using ::?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.2

I just got stuck on this for a while. Take this base:

```
module Top
  class Test
  end

  module Foo
  end
end
```

Later, I can define classes inside `Foo` that extends `Test` by doing this:

```
module Top
  module Foo
    class SomeTest < Test
    end
  end
end
```

However, if I try to minimize indentation by using `::` to specify the module:

```
module Top::Foo
  class Failure < Test
  end
end
```

This fails with:

> NameError: uninitialized constant Top::Foo::Test

Is this a bug, or is it just a logical consequence of the way Ruby resolves variable names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this a bug, or is it just a logical consequence

It's a "quirk". Some consider it a bug.

Parent scopes used for looking up unresolved constants are determined by module nesting. It just so happens that when you use `module Top::Foo`, it creates just one level of nesting instead of two. Observe:

```
module Top
  module Foo
    class SomeTest
      Module.nesting # => [Top::Foo::SomeTest, Top::Foo, Top]
    end
  end
end

module Top::Foo
  class SomeTest
    Module.nesting # => [Top::Foo::SomeTest, Top::Foo]
  end
end
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me :P But very informative response, thank you

Comment: I would say I consider it a bug, has anyone found a bug report in ruby about this? I'd like to contribute to discussion and look at what would be involved in fixing this.

Comment: Note: found a link stating that it's intentional [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11705)

Comment: [This](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6810) appears to be the bug report for this behaviour. Let's hope Matz decides to pick it up. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. Using `::` changes the scope of constant lookup and expects `Test` to be defined under `Top::Foo`.

To get the expected result, you could write:

```
module Top::Foo
  class SomeTest < Top::Test
  end
end
```

or:

```
module Top
  class Foo::SomeTest < Test
  end
end
```

or even:

```
class Top::Foo::SomeTest < Top::Test
end
```