# Which class get inherited when using nested class

Tags: ruby

```
class Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

Which class get inherited when I using nested class?

```
class Admin < ApplicationController
  class ApplicationController
  end
end
```

or

```
class Admin 
  class ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  end
end
```

I think the second one is the winner, because what I understand `Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController` is get the `ApplicationController` inside `Admin` namespace and make it inherit from `ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is what is the equivalent of this line:

```
class Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
```

Then your second assumption is correct, it is equivalent to:

```
class Admin 
  class ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  end
end
```

Few sidenotes though:

1. Your current design exposes bad naming
2. Why not make `Admin` a module instead of class?
3. Prefer using the explicit form instead of nested one - you'll never get confused.
4. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338131/why-doesnt-ruby-find-classes-in-a-higher-scope-when-module-is-specified-using) about some difference in levels of nesting between two forms of class definitions.

Comment: Thanks, Andrey. I am new to Rails. I am reading Rails in Action 4. The first code block is the sample code from the book. The reason I ask this question is because Rubocop tell me not use compact format.

Comment: @LiXinyang I somehow missed your comment. I believe Rubocop's warnings are worth of listening. Good that you're using it (I do, too)