# Different Ways of Namespacing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, namespaces

AFAIK I know these two ways of namespacing in ruby:

```
module Cat
  class Lion
    def hunt
      p 'roaming for prey ...'
    end
  end

  class Cheetah
    def hunt
      Lion.new.hunt
      p 'Oops there is a lion. Hide first ...'
    end
  end
end

class Cat::MountainLion
  def hunt
    Lion.new.hunt
    p 'roaming for prey ... (since I dont live in the same continent as lion)'
  end
end

Cat::Cheetah.new.hunt
Cat::MountainLion.new.hunt
```

Why is it the `Cat::MountainLion.new.hunt` doesn't work? Are namespace declared as `module` differs to those declared as prefix to class `class Cat::`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338131/why-doesnt-ruby-find-classes-in-a-higher-scope-when-module-is-specified-using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two ways differ in the constant lookup. The former looks for `Lion` constant in `Cat` namespace, which is correct. The latter looks for `::Lion`, in global namespace, which is obviously incorrect, since you don't have such constant.

For more information about this topic, please visit this page:
https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html

Comment: The former looks for `Lion` in `Cat::Cheetah`, then in `Cat` and finally at the top-level. Whereas the latter looks in `Cat::MountainLion` and then at the top-level, thus skipping `Cat`.