# Why does Ruby constant lookup sometimes fail when using :: notation?

Tags: ruby

If I have the following modules:

```
module Foo
end

module Foo::Bar
  def print
    puts "something"
  end
end
```

Why does this usage style work?

```
module Foo
  class Baz
    include Bar
  end
end

Foo::Baz.new.print
```

But this usage style errors with "uninitialized constant Foo::Baz::Bar (NameError)"?

```
class Foo::Baz
  include Bar
end

Foo::Baz.new.print
```

Isn't the second usage case just shorthand for the first one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't Ruby find classes in a higher scope when module is specified using ::?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338131/why-doesnt-ruby-find-classes-in-a-higher-scope-when-module-is-specified-using)

Comment: Yes, thanks @engineersmnky! :)